# System Environment Variable with connection string returns null value when called in .net core 2.1

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, .net-core, environment-variables

I am trying to store my connection string into my system(windows 10) environment variable to protect my sensitive information before going to production.

When I do call my environment variables, it returns a null value. I don't have any errors.

I did follow those tutorials:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TNghzUs0BQI&fbclid=IwAR2YUue7740qgVT_5z04xruel-4NwOuUyjQj5E63T1UpYqRoVuz_81DiZTo

https://medium.com/@gparlakov/the-confusion-of-asp-net-configuration-with-environment-variables-c06c545ef732

I don't see what I am missing here. For what I understand, if I don't use prefixes, I juste need to set the environment variable in my system and then make the call.

Here is an image of my environment variable. I do provide a link, because I don't have enough internet points to post the image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9uX5.png

This is my Startup.cs

```
        private IConfiguration _configuration;

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;

        }
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddDbContext<dbApplicationServiceNavada>(options => options.UseMySql(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASNConnStr")));

            services.AddScoped<IEmployeeData, SqlEmployeeData>();
            services.AddScoped<ILanguageData, SqlLanguageData>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
                                IHostingEnvironment env,
                                IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            //Show exception stack trace when in dev mode
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            //Use files in wwwroot folder
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            //Defines the available routes
            app.UseMvc(ConfigureRoutes);

            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                var RNA = configuration["RouteNA"];
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(RNA);
            });
        }
```

This is my webHostBuilder in Program.cs

```
        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                {
                    config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                })
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
```

I also see that I have a launchSettings.json file with Environment variables in there, but I wonder if it's the same thing as system environement variables.

**FIRST EDIT:**

As mentioned in the answer, I did rename my environment variable to

```
MYSQLCONNSTR_ASNConnStr
```

I also removed the part in my program.cs to load environmental variable.

Now when I debug the project, I see in my _confirguration.Providers my environment variable getting loaded.
Here is a picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuEBJ.png

When I do

```
services.AddDbContext<dbApplicationServiceNavada>(options => options.UseMySql(_configuration.GetConnectionString("ASNConnStr")));
```

It still returns a null value. I don't seem to be able to get the variable.

Picture of the error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyIWT.png

**SECOND EDIT:**

Now the problem is solved, I just want to add to the contributor Simply Ged, that instead of :

```
services.AddDbContext<dbApplicationServiceNavada>(options => options.UseMySql(_configuration.GetConnectionString("ASNConnStr")));
```

I had to do:

```
services.AddDbContext<dbApplicationServiceNavada>(options => options.UseMySql(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASNConnStr")));
```

Now everything works fine!

**THIRD EDIT:**

After restarting my computer, this line of code works:

```
services.AddDbContext<dbApplicationServiceNavada>(options => options.UseMySql(_configuration.GetConnectionString("ASNConnStr")));
```

It appears that we need to restart the computer/server in order to get the environmental variable adequatly.

In Conclusion, the answer of the contributor Simply Ged was right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to add `ConfigureAppConfiguration` to add environment variables to the configuration as it is done as part of `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder`. See [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-2.2) for details about what the default builder provides.

Knowing that, you can replace read your connection string from the `Configuration` class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddDbContext<dbApplicationServiceNavada>(options => options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ASNConnStr")));

    ....
}
```

The `Configuration` class will load the correct value based on the order that is defined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-2.2#set-up-a-host)

You would also need to change your environment variable name to the following:

```
MYSQLCONNSTR_ASNConnStr
```

You can read more about the Configuration in .NET Core [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#environment-variables-configuration-provider)